# "Press any key to exit" command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, autohotkey

```
^!a::
      hwnd := WinExist("A")
      for Window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows  
          if (window.hwnd==hwnd) {
              Selection := Window.Document.SelectedItems
              for Items in Selection
                  Path_to_Selection := Items.path
          }
run %ComSpec% /k certutil -hashfile "%Path_to_Selection%" md5
return
```

this is ahk script which lets you retrieve the md5 hash when you click on any file and press ctrl + alt + a in windows explorer. It opens the command prompt with file path and hash information in it.
It works flawlessly, but I want to go one step further for convenience.

maybe two things come to my mind. it will be great if:

1. the prompt window closes if any key is pressed, not just X button at the upper right.
2. the prompt window shows only hash value. no additional information such as "MD5 hash of file ping.txt:" or "CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully." kind of things.

so this question is related in both batch script and autohotkey script.
any ideas? I am not tech savvy. Just got this script somewhere on the internet and I just changed the hotkey for my liking.

Answer (score 1):

Select a file in Explorer or Desktop and press `Ctrl+Alt+A` to get the MD5 hash of that file:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class Progman") ; Explorer or Desktop

    ^!a::
        FileFullPath := Explorer_GetSelection()
        Hash := FileMD5(FileFullPath)
        MsgBox, % Hash
    return

#If 

; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=60403&p=255273#p255256
Explorer_GetSelection(){
   WinGetClass, winClass, % "ahk_id" . hWnd := WinExist("A")
   if !(winClass ~="Progman|WorkerW|(Cabinet|Explore)WClass")
      Return
   shellWindows := ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
   if (winClass ~= "Progman|WorkerW")
      shellFolderView := shellWindows.FindWindowSW(0, 0, SWC_DESKTOP := 8, 0, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH := 1).Document
   else {
      for window in shellWindows
       try  if (hWnd = window.HWND) && (shellFolderView := window.Document)
            break
   }
   for item in shellFolderView.SelectedItems
      result .= (result = "" ? "" : "`n") . item.Path
   if !result
      result := shellFolderView.Folder.Self.Path
   Return result
}

; https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/16409-md5/page-3#entry342246
FileMD5( sFile="", cSz=4 ) {
    cSz  := (cSz<0||cSz>8) ? 2**22 : 2**(18+cSz), VarSetCapacity( Buffer,cSz,0 )
    hFil := DllCall( "CreateFile", Str,sFile,UInt,0x80000000, Int,1,Int,0,Int,3,Int,0,Int,0 )
    IfLess,hFil,1, Return,hFil
    DllCall( "GetFileSizeEx", UInt,hFil, Str,Buffer ),   fSz := NumGet( Buffer,0,"Int64" )
    VarSetCapacity( MD5_CTX,104,0 ),    DllCall( "advapi32\MD5Init", Str,MD5_CTX )
    Loop % ( fSz//cSz+!!Mod(fSz,cSz) )
    DllCall( "ReadFile", UInt,hFil, Str,Buffer, UInt,cSz, UIntP,bytesRead, UInt,0 )
    , DllCall( "advapi32\MD5Update", Str,MD5_CTX, Str,Buffer, UInt,bytesRead )
    DllCall( "advapi32\MD5Final", Str,MD5_CTX ), DllCall( "CloseHandle", UInt,hFil )
    Loop % StrLen( Hex:="123456789ABCDEF0" )
    N := NumGet( MD5_CTX,87+A_Index,"Char"), MD5 .= SubStr(Hex,N>>4,1) . SubStr(Hex,N&15,1)
    Return MD5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, every line has a comment on end for clarification:

```
^!a::
    CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
    Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Path
    ClipWait, 0  ; Prevent Waiting Indefinitely For Copy
    If (!CLIPBOARD)  ; IF Clipboard EMPTY
    {
        SoundPlay, C:\Windows\Media\Windows Critical Stop.wav  ; Error Sound
        MsgBox, 262160, ERROR, File not selected!  ; Clipboard Empty
    }
    Else  ; ELSE
    {
        path := CLIPBOARD  ; path
        RunWait, cmd /c certutil -hashfile "%path%" md5 | clip, , Hide  ; certutil
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, MD5 hash of %path%:  ; Clean String
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.  ; Clean String
        hash := CLIPBOARD  ; hash
        StringTrimLeft, hash, hash, 2  ; Trim String
        StringTrimRight, hash, hash, 4  ; Trim String
        Run, cmd /k @echo off && echo %hash% && pause>nul && exit  ; Display Hash Only & Exit CMD On Any Key Press
    }
Return
```

Or you can display hash in a message box:

```
^!a::
    CLIPBOARD := ""  ; Clear Clipboard
    Send, {Control Down}{c}{Control Up}  ; Copy File Path
    ClipWait, 0  ; Prevent Waiting Indefinitely For Copy
    If (!CLIPBOARD)  ; IF Clipboard EMPTY
    {
        SoundPlay, C:\Windows\Media\Windows Critical Stop.wav  ; Error Sound
        MsgBox, 262160, ERROR, File not selected!  ; Clipboard Empty
    }
    Else  ; ELSE
    {
        path := CLIPBOARD  ; path
        RunWait, cmd /c certutil -hashfile "%path%" md5 | clip, , Hide  ; certutil
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, MD5 hash of %path%:  ; Clean String
        StringReplace, CLIPBOARD, CLIPBOARD, CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.  ; Clean String
        hash := CLIPBOARD  ; hash
        StringTrimLeft, hash, hash, 2  ; Trim String
        StringTrimRight, hash, hash, 4  ; Trim String
        IfNotExist, IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk  ; Create IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk
        {
            IfAnyKeyPressedClose := 
            (LTrim
            "#SingleInstance Force
            Input, SingleKey, L1, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{CapsLock}{NumLock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
            WinClose, HASH ahk_class #32770 ahk_exe AutoHotkey.exe
            ExitApp"
            )  ; Create IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk
            FileDelete, IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk  ; Create IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk
            FileAppend, %IfAnyKeyPressedClose%, IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk  ; Create IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk
        }
        Run, IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk  ; Run IfAnyKeyPressedClose.ahk
        MsgBox, 262144, HASH, %hash%  ; Display hash
    }
Return
```